# Does there exist an $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x)) = x^3 + 1$?

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

This (question 6) was from the November $2022$ NZ maths olympiad workshop (I couldn't find the online one, even on the Wayback Machine so I'm emailing them).

All I know is that $f$ is bijective (injective & surjective).

Assume that $f$ is *not* injective, ie there exist $x_1 < x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

$$
\begin{align}
  f(x_1) &= f(x_2) \\[1ex]
  f(f(x_1)) &= f(f(x_2)) \\[1ex]
  x_1^3 + 1 &= x_2^3 + 1 \\[1ex]
  x_1^3 &= x_2^3 \\[1ex]
  x_1 &= x_2 \ \large{\unicode{x21af}}
\end{align}
$$
The last line is true since $x \mapsto x^3$ is an injective function. (it is strictly monotonic)

Assume that $f$ is *not* surjective, ie there exists a $y_0$ such that $\forall x : f(x) \neq y_0$

$$
\begin{align}
  f(x) &\neq y_0 \\[1ex]
  f(f(x)) &\neq f(y_0),\quad (f \text{ is injective})  \\[1ex]
  x^3 + 1 &\neq f(y_0) \ \large{\unicode{x21af}}
\end{align}
$$

This is a contradiction since $x^3 + 1$ spans the reals, so $f$ is bijective. I have a feeling that $f$ is discontinuous, although I can't prove it.

I find it hard to even find specific values of $f$, like I only know that

$$f(\alpha) = \alpha$$

where $\alpha$ is the real solution to $x = x^3 + 1$. Trying to evaluate $f$ at other points results in other unknown values.

Below I have rearranged the functional equation (Wolfram Alpha couldn't solve it). Since $f$ is bijective there must be an inverse.

$$
\begin{align}
  f(f(x)) &= x^3 + 1 \\[1ex]
  f(x) &= f^{-1}\left(x^3 + 1 \right) \\[1ex]
  f(x) &= \left[ f^{-1}(x) \right]^3 + 1 \ \text{(from eqn 1)}\\[1ex]
  f^{-1}\left(x^3 + 1 \right) &= \left[ f^{-1}(x) \right]^3 + 1 \\[1ex]
\end{align}
$$
Alternatively one could rearrange the equation in terms of $f$
$$
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= f^{-1}\left(x^3 + 1 \right) \\[1ex]
  f\left( \sqrt[3]{x - 1} \right) &= f^{-1}(x) \\[1ex]
  \left[ f\left( \sqrt[3]{x - 1} \right) \right]^3 + 1 &= \left[ f^{-1}(x) \right]^3 + 1 \\[1ex]
  f(x) &= \left[ f\left( \sqrt[3]{x - 1} \right) \right]^3 + 1 \\[1ex]
  f\left(x^3 + 1 \right) &= \left[ f(x) \right]^3 + 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150195/discussion-on-question-by-nick-zheng-does-there-exist-an-f-mathbbr-to-mat); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This spells out an [argument proposed by user tomasz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820589/does-there-exist-an-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-such-that-ffx-x3-1#comment10259521_4820589).

First assume that $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is 1-1, onto, and satisfies $g(x)>x$. Each orbit of the action of $g$ on $\mathbb R$ is a copy of $\mathbb Z$, with $g$ acting on each orbit by $n\mapsto n+1$.  Let $X$ be the space of orbits.  By choosing a single element in each orbit, we can consider that $X\subseteq \mathbb R$. Thus we have a 1-1 onto map $\phi\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb Z\times X$, where $X\subseteq \mathbb R$.  Via $\phi$, it suffices to define a suitable function $f$ ("operator-theoretic square root of $g$") on $\mathbb Z\times X$.  Choose a fixed-point-free involution $\iota\colon X\to X$.  We define $f$ by setting $f(n,x)=(n,\iota(x))$ if $x<\iota(x)$, and $f(n,x)=(n+1,\iota(x))$ otherwise.  Then the composition $f\circ f$ sends $(n,x)$ to $(n+1,\iota\circ\iota (x))=(n+1,x)$, which corresponds to $g$ via the correspondence $\phi$.

Since each orbit is discrete, one can avoid the use of the axiom of choice in choosing a subset $X\subseteq \mathbb R$, by choosing the representative real number in each orbit to be the smallest positive number in the orbit.  Doing the same for $\iota$ may require further work.

Now our $g(x)=x^3+1$ has a fixed point $-2<\alpha<-1$ so the proof will be slightly more complicated.  First, we define $f(\alpha)=\alpha$.  It remains to define $f$ separately on the intervals $(-\infty,\alpha)$ and $(\alpha,\infty)$.  On the latter, $f$ satisfies the condition $f(x)>x$, whereas on the former, $f$ satisfies a similar condition $f(x)<x$, so a similar argument can be applied.

Comment: This answer is a bit deep for me, so I've got a few questions. 
When you say that $g(x) = x^3 + 1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is a copy of $\mathbb{N}$, is that the same thing as "it is countably infinite"? Also, why does $\iota$ have to be free of fixed points?

Comment: I'm not sure you can really make this argument choice-free. The choice of representatives for $X$ is not the problem, its the choice of the involution $\iota$. Otherwise, thanks for spelling this out and fixing my mistakes, nice answer!

Comment: @NickZheng: each orbit of $g$ is a copy of the integers: after fixing a point $x_0$ in the orbit, $k\mapsto g^k(x_0)$ is a bijection. If $\iota$ had fixed points, then $f$ would not be well-defined (note that it has two clauses depending on whether $\iota(x)$ is bigger or smaller than $x$).

Comment: @MikhailKatz Also, as for choosing the representatives for orbits, being discrete is not what you need for your choice to work, it's being bounded away from $0$ (from the above). For example, the set of fractions $\frac{1}{n}$ is discrete, but it has no smallest positive element. You also need to know that each orbit actually has positive elements. But I think this actually is true in this example.

Comment: @tomasz, if an orbit accumulates on $0$ then $0$ will be a fixed point, which is not the case under the assumption of the first part of the argument.

Comment: @tomasz, with regard to the involution: I think choice can be avoided in the specific example of $x^3+1$.  This is because the domain naturally breaks down into the fixed point $\alpha$ and the infinite integrals on both sides.  I believe one can choose the corresponding set $X$ to be connected on both sides, and then one can just use a linear correspondence between the two $X$'s as the involution.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Yes, you're right, that should work. There would still be an issue with a single orbit, I guess, but this can be worked around using some standard trick with enumerating a countable set.

Comment: @tomasz, the only single orbit here would be the orbit of $\alpha$, which is a fixed point for the function $f$ by definition.  What kind of problem would one encounter here?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Nevermind. I misunderstood your argument.